# Disable Azure/Office MFA on all users

Tags: azure, authentication, login, microsoft-office-365, azure-mfa

We have created a new Office Tenant.
Now all users are required to use the Multi Factor Authentication.
How can I disable this policy?

I know that I can't disable it for gloabl admins. 
That's fine - but I need to disable this for all users.

In the office administration, the MFA is disabled on every user, but on login, they receive a promt to activate this.

Comment: Have you disabled security defaults in your Azure AD properties?

Comment: You can disable MFA for anyone.  This is not the default setting on a subscription.  Did you create the subscription?